# Windows String Formats

Tags: c++, windows, string, type-conversion

This is an absolutely newbie's question.

I am writing my first C++ console Application.
I retrieve the command line arguments using `CommandLineToArgvW`.
The second argument is supposed to be an integer, so I would like to convert the string to an integer.
Problem: `atoi` gets a `const char *` but `CommandLineToArgvW` returns `PWSTR *`.
Do I need to start using conversion functions, or am I (hopefully) missing something.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use atoi. Use the C++ standard library.

Comment: wcstol would be the closest thing to atoi for narrow strings, though it is indeed not very "C++". You can also construct an std::wstring from your PWSTR* and use std::stoi.